# Driver API - Get /partners/trips() for current ride

Tags: android

Is it possible to retrieve the trip currently being done by the driver, or only the ones already finished?

Example: Let's say there is a request for the driver and he/she has accepted it, and the driver is going to take the passenger. Will this trip be retrieved during the GET /partner/trips API call?